# Connect to a SSH server (in VM) via an intermediary SSH server (in docker)

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, proxy

I have 2 SSH servers (server1 is running in a docker container, server2 is running in a VM).
From my laptop, I can connect to the first one (ssh server1) but not to the second one because of security reasons.
Yet I can connect to the second server from server1 (ssh server2).

Is there a way I can connect to server2 from my laptop?

Here is the .ssh/config file that is deployed on my laptop and server1:

```
Host server1
    HostName 127.0.0.1
    User debian
    Port 2222
    IdentityFile /home/guillaume/.ssh/id_rsa

Host server2
    HostName 172.29.160.1
    User debian
    Port 1022
    IdentityFile /config/id_rsa
```

I tried the ssh chaining:

```
ssh server1 ssh server2
```

While this does work, it won't allow me to run docker commands in server2 from my laptop.

I also tried the jump:

```
ssh -J server1 server2
```

But it returns:

```
channel 0: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
stdio forwarding failed
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
Connection closed by UNKNOWN port 65535
```

I also tried the proxy command:

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p server2" server1
```

But the command blocks forever.

Comment: Well,  I haven't messed around that much with going from one SSH server to another but i'd just note that there's no need to add complexity of VM and Docker into your question..   This might answer it, tells you to comment out this line  in sshd_config https://serverfault.com/questions/535412/how-to-solve-the-open-failed-administratively-prohibited-open-failed-when-us  `AllowTcpForwarding no` or try `AllowTcpForwarding yes`

Comment: If you connect to server1 via ssh and then try to manually connect to server2, does that work?

Comment: @tink he wrote about "ssh server1 ssh server2"  which sounds like what you're saying

Comment: @barlop - to me that looks like an attempt at a single command to get there. Let's see what he comes back with ...

Comment: @tink it's a single command that would do the same as the manual thing you said, and he said it does work. So manually doing it would do the same,  but he said of that, that  " it won't allow me to run docker commands in server2 from my laptop.". I haven't used docker that much and he hasn't explained exactly what he means re docker, maybe  you know?

Comment: @tiny and barlop, Indeed, "ssh server1 ssh server2" works but I can't use this approch to run docker commands from the laptop to server2 because I would need to use commands like "docker -H ssh://server2 run ..." which expect a single hostname to the target server.

Comment: Btw, you have the order of your servers wrong in your proxy command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks a lot for the hints in the comment section of the answer!
I got it working with two changes.

- set AllowTcpForwarding to yes in the intermediate server (/etc/ssh/sshd_config)
- update the .ssh/config on the laptop as follow

```
Host server1
  HostName 127.0.0.1
  User debian
  Port 2222
  IdentityFile /home/guillaume/.ssh/id_rsa

Host server2
  HostName 172.29.160.1
  User debian
  Port 1022
  IdentityFile /home/guillaume/.ssh/id_rsa  # put the path to the private key on the laptop
  ProxyCommand ssh server1 -W %h:%p         # added this line
```

Comment: @barlop Sure, that's what I meant. I'll update the answer!